# Django - Accepting full sentence in query parameters

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I'm putting together a small API that just converts the message coming in to Spongebob mockcase.

I've got everything rolling, but coming back I'm realizing I've been testing with a single value & thus just noticed the following URL entry will not be able to accept spaces/%20.

```
url(r'^mock/(?P<message>\w+)/$',mock, name='mock'),
```

I've looked all over, but not sure how to phrase what I'm looking for appropriately to find anything useful. What would I be looking for to accept a full sentence.

Worth noting this will be coming from a chat message, therefore, it will be sent as is, not percent encoded.

Comment: try changing `\w+` to `[\w ]+`

Comment: Probably, it is safer to use `r'^mock/(?P<message>[^/]+)/$` to avoid adding more and more "whitelisted" chars later. `[^/]+` matches 1 or more chars other than `/`

Comment: Could you guys explain the differences (or drop a Regex validator with some test strings) in your answers? Both work seemingly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to put things like that as URL parameters. Instead it should be in the querystring: for example `mysite.com/mock/?message=Message+goes+here`.

The URL should just be:

```
url('^mock/$', ...)
```

and the view then just gets the data from `request.GET['message']`.

Comment: That's actually what I had thought originally, but saw some similar cases where they urged against it. What're the dangers in capturing in URL parameters vs query string?

Answer (score 0):

You may fix your immediate issue using

```
r'^mock/(?P<message>[^/]+)/?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MPiGaT/2)

Here, `[^/]+` matches any one or more chars other than `/` and the `/?` matches an optional `/` at the end of the string (`$`).